# .Settings file (.NET), working with a sub

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a sub which will allow me to pass in 2 values, one is the name of a button, the other is a setting name contained within the .Settings file. I'm a noob to .NET and have no idea how I might do this. Anyone? thanks

```
 private void setZoneValues(System.Windows.Forms.Button button, Settings1 setting)
    {
        if (button.BackColor == System.Drawing.Color.Lime)
        {
            button.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Tomato;
            Settings1.Default.<**setting**> = false;
        }

        else if (btnZone1.BackColor == System.Drawing.Color.Tomato)
        {
            btnZone1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Lime;
            Settings1.Default.<**setting**>= true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you saying you don't know how to create a setting, or you don't know how to reference it? Or something else entirely....

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass in the setting name as a string, and then do:

```
private void setZoneValues(System.Windows.Forms.Button button, string setting)  
{
    ...
    Settings1.Default[setting] = true; 
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks RedFilter - that did the job. Didn't know you could perform such a trick! Will be handy in the future no doubt

Answer (score 0):

1. Select your button in designer.
2. In the properties window find '(Application Settings)' and expand it
3. Select '(PropertyBinding)'
4. Find property Backcolor in list and create new setting for it with name e.g. "MyButtonColor"

TThat creates color property with name 'MyButtonColor' in defatult application settings and binds it to button's BackColor property.

Next goes coding:

```
private void setZoneValues(Button button, string setting)  
{
    // change button color
    button.BackColor = (button.BackColor == Color.Lime) ? 
                        Color.Tomato : Color.Lime;
}
```

That's all. When you call `Settings.Default.Save();` current button's BackColor value will be saved to setting file. When you start application again, value from settings file will be assigned to button's BackColor.

UPDATE: Of course, you can add settings manually, but then you'll need to load and update them manually. E.g. in Form_Load event handler:

```
button1.BackColor = Settings.Default.MyButtonColor;
```

And after changing color in setZoneValues method:

```
Settings.Default.MyButtonColor = button.BackColor;
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have specified a setting with name "Test" in Settings.settings. You can access that setting using following line of code:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Test
```

Your setting will act like a property in c#. You will be able to get and set value to it.